# Como puedo ingresar unos datos de una tablaExcel a un formulario web?

Tags: python, excel, selenium

buen día. Estoy intentando ingresar una columna en especifico de una tabla de excel a un formulario web. La columna es "Auditores"

Ingreso el archivo de excel a mi código con esto: Es un archivo con 3 columnas, cada columna tiene su titulo(fila 1), posterior a esto tiene 44 filas(a partir de la fila 2)

```
b = op.load_workbook ('BaseAuditores_mx.xlsx', use_iterators = True)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Hoja1')
op.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows()
```

es la columna #3 y esta tiene 44 filas

```
col_name = 'Global SSO/RRSSS'
start_row = 2
end_row = 44

range_expr = "{col}{start_row}:{col}{end_row}".format(
    col = col_name, start_row = start_row, end_row = end_row)
```

No entiendo muy bien, soy bastante nuevo con esto, pero quisier saber como puedo cambiar de usuario. La idea principal es que cambie de usuario cada que se completa el registro. Este es el xpath del campo de auditor. Para este ejemplo estoy usando un solo usuario, pero quiero que vaya cambiando, no entiendo muy bien como hacerlo, creo que es con un for, pero no sé como hacerlo, alguien podría explicarme como hacerlo?

```
auditor = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="uid"]')
auditor.clear()
auditor.send_keys("carlos")
time.sleep(2)
```

Cuando ingreso el usuario, oprime un botón y carga los datos de este.

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.HOME)
time.sleep(1)
buscarb = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='button']")
buscarb.click()
time.sleep(3)
```

Este mismo proceso necesito hacerlo pero con todos los que estan en la base de excel.

Les agradecería la ayuda, muchas gracias

Comment: Creo que seria mas facil si proporciones un ejemplo de los datos de tu Excel :

Comment: Lo que quieres es cambiar la información de un usuario? o añadir un usuario a tu Excel?

Comment: Hola, el excel esta compuesto por tres columnas, la primera columna es el nombre de la persona, la segunda es el puesto de trabajo y la tercera es el ID. Yo necesito trabajar con el ID de cada persona.  en la instancia donde dice "Auditor" al abrir la página se debe ingresar el ID automático de cada persona y posterior a esto, darle en el boton de buscar.

Comment: La tabla esta compuesta por tres columnas. las que nombre anteriormente, y 45 filas (la primera son los titulos) las 44 restantes es la información de cada persona. Yo debo trabajar desde la fila 2 hasta las 45

Comment: entiendo como esta compuesto, pero que quieres hacer en el Excel? quieres cambiar datos o quieres agregar datos?

Comment: en el excel nada, quiero que los datos del ID que hacen parte del excel ingresen por medio de código automaticamente, al espacio de texto de auditor en la pagina web. No se si me entiendes :(

Comment: quieres mostrar los datos del Excel en la web?

Comment: si, exacto, ingresarlos al formulario de la pagina web

Comment: por la etiqueta `selenium` supongo que estas enviando una solicitud `POST`, no?

Comment: si, he averiguado y sé que es con selenium, y haciendo webscraping, la etiqueta de auditor en la pagina es la que mostraba en el código. Lo que no sé es como hacer que cada que termine de cargar la informacion de una persona, cambie a la otra de inmediato

Comment: no soy experto en selenium, pero lo puedes hacer con un ciclo `for`, una vez carga la información vuelves a la pagina *principal* y haces el mismo procedimiento n veces

Comment: jaja ese es el problema, hasta ahora estoy aprendiendo, no se como hacerlo

Comment: el dato que coloques sera enviado por la pagina para que te devuelva la informacion, esto se hace mediante una solicitud HTTP (pagina->backend) esto devolvera un estado HTTP (2xx,3xx,4xx,5xx), cuandos recives el estado significa que ya te han dado la informacion